Mysql Trigger cannot set a new value
I have a problem with my Trigger sql, which is always set the id_tingkatan to 4 no matter what I do, having checking the nomor_reference to set the id to 5 is still not working
BEGIN
  -- Check if the new value of id_tingkatan_wewenang is NULL 
  IF NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 2; 
  END IF; 
  
  IF NEW.nomor_reference is NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 5;
  END IF;

  -- Check if tgl_keluar_verifikator is NOT NULL and catatan_verifikator is NULL
  IF NEW.tgl_keluar_verifikator IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 4;
  ELSEIF OLD.tgl_keluar_verifikator IS NOT NULL AND OLD.catatan_verifikator IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang=3;
  ELSEIF NEW.tgl_keluar_verifikator IS NOT NULL AND
      NEW.catatan_verifikator IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang=1; 
    
  ELSE 
    -- Check if the new value of id_jumlah_total_tagihan is 1 
    IF NEW.id_jumlah_total_tagihan = 1 THEN 
      SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 3; 
    ELSE 
      SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 5; 
    END IF; 

    -- Check status K3
    IF NEW.id_status_k3 = 1 THEN 
      SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 3; 
    ELSEIF NEW.id_status_k3 = 2 THEN 
      SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 1; 
    END IF; 
  END IF;


  -- Final fallback (if necessary)
  IF NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.id_tingkatan_wewenang = 2; 
  END IF;
END

and this is the DDL Creation Table
CREATE TABLE `tagihan` (
  `id_tagihan` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_voucher` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nama_vendor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nama_tagihan` text NOT NULL,
  `unit_kerja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nominal` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `path_dokumen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_jenis_tagihan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_jumlah_total_tagihan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_status_k3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_pembuatan_voucher` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_persetujuan_voucher` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_verifikator` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_keluar_verifikator` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `catatan_verifikator` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_review_manajemen` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_penyampaian_review` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `selesai_perbaikan` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `selesai_akhir` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_out_keu_perpajakan` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_out_ka_dak` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_out_vp_sdk` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_out_dir_kpm` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_kasir` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_input_bri` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_approve_bri_anggaran` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_approve_ka_dak` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_release` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomor_posting` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomor_reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_akp_arsip` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `durasi_pembayaran` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluasi_verifikasi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tingkatan_wewenang` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_status_pembayaran` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persentase_tahapan` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_posisi_tagihan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_status_penyelesaian` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

What I do is literally make the priority like make the if condition of nomor_reference is not null on top and bottom and it still not work, and make the double params like if nomor_reference is not null and ... it still not working and still updating the value of id_tingkatan_wewenang to 4
What I'm expecting is make when the nomor_reference is not null update the id to 5, or if you guys want to try, this is the link for the database
https://github.com/PACE1000/db.git

Is this SQL or is it Mysql ?

You might update the question with the DDL creation code for your table so that someone can see what the table looks like?

There is no id_tingkatan in the code. Do you mean id_tingkatan_wewenang?

This condition: ELSEIF NEW.tgl_keluar_verifikator IS NOT NULL AND NEW.catatan_verifikator IS NOT NULL THEN can never succeed, because you already check NEW.tgl_keluar_verifikator IS NOT NULL in the first IF of that block.

You need to check more specific conditions before more general conditions that include it.

Yeah, I mean is id_tingkatan_wewenang

I Just Add the DDL Creation Code

maybe I will try to make that one chunk of code into several trigger maybe it solve


IF column IS NULL THEN SET column = value END should be replaced with SET column = COALESCE(column, value) 2) Your "Final fallback" will fire never due to the most first IF.

